# How do I filter a GeoJson file for specific countries?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, nested, geojson

Challenge: I'm trying to create a new dictionary from my geojson dictionary that is filtered for only the countries of interest because the raw geojson file is too large for visualization.

I have a geojson file with the below form, which I've created an empty dictionary to replicate:

```
newData = {'features': {},
           'properties':{'ADMIN':"",
                         'ISO_A3':"",
                         },
           'geometry':{'type':"",
                       'coordinates':""
                       },
           'id':""
           }
```

Below is an example of one of the elements from the geojson file:

```
data['features'][3]

{'type': 'Feature',
 'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Aruba', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
 'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
  'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],
    [-69.93639075399994, 12.53172435100005],
    [-69.92467200399994, 12.519232489000046],
    [-69.91576087099992, 12.497015692000076],
    [-69.88019771999984, 12.453558661000045],
    [-69.87682044199994, 12.427394924000097],
    [-69.88809160099993, 12.417669989000046],
    [-69.90880286399994, 12.417792059000107],
    [-69.93053137899989, 12.425970770000035],
    [-69.94513912699992, 12.44037506700009],
    [-69.92467200399994, 12.44037506700009],
    [-69.92467200399994, 12.447211005000014],
    [-69.95856686099992, 12.463202216000099],
    [-70.02765865799992, 12.522935289000088],
    [-70.04808508999989, 12.53115469000008],
    [-70.05809485599988, 12.537176825000088],
    [-70.06240800699987, 12.546820380000057],
    [-70.06037350199995, 12.556952216000113],
    [-70.0510961579999, 12.574042059000064],
    [-70.04873613199993, 12.583726304000024],
    [-70.05264238199993, 12.600002346000053],
    [-70.05964107999992, 12.614243882000054],
    [-70.06110592399997, 12.625392971000068],
    [-70.04873613199993, 12.632147528000104],
    [-70.00715084499987, 12.5855166690001],
    [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]]},
 'id': 'ABW'}
```

I also have a data frame object of the countries that I'm actually interested in analyzing:

```
df_Country.head()
2                   Italy
3                   Spain
4                Portugal
5    United Arab Emirates
6                   Egypt
```

This file has a number of countries that are unnecessary for the analysis I'm performing so I'd like to filter them out. I believe that this is similar to filtering a nested dictionary. To do this I've tried to create an empty dictionary and loop through it adding in the values of the geo_data whenever I have a match to df_Countries. Below is what I've attempted:

```
for i in range(len(data['features'])):
  if data['features'][i]['properties']['ADMIN'] in df_Country:
    newData['properties']['ADMIN'] = data['features'][i]['properties']['ADMIN']
    newData['properties']['ISO_A3'] = data['features'][i]['properties']['ISO_A3']
    newData['geometry']['type'] = data['features'][i]['geometry']['type']
    newData['geometry']['coordinates'] = data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates']
    newData['id'] = data['features'][i]['id']
```

At the end of this, my newData dictionary is still empty. Any thoughts? Thank you in advance!

Comment: so `ADMIN` is the name of the country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were really close! You can do a one-liner list comprehension like this:

```py
# example data
geo_json = [
    {'type': 'Feature',
     'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Italy', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
     'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
                  'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],
                                   [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]]},
        'id': 'ABW'},
    {'type': 'Feature',
     'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Aruba', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
     'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
                  'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],
                                   [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]]},
        'id': 'ABW'},
    {'type': 'Feature',
     'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Spain', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
     'geometry': {'type': 'Polygon',
                  'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],
                                   [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]]},
        'id': 'ABW'},
]

# countries you want
countries = ['Italy', 'Spain']

# new list of geo_json but only ones with ['properties']['ADMIN'] in countries
filtered = [geo for geo in geo_json if geo['properties']['ADMIN'] in countries]

# pretty print the results
from pprint import pprint
pprint(filtered)
```

The comparable `for` loop to that comprehension would look like:

```py
filtered = []
for geo in geo_json:
    if geo['properties']['ADMIN'] in countries:
        filtered.append(geo)
```

Output (just Spain and Italy, there were 3 in `geo_json`):

```py
[{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],  
                                [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]],
               'type': 'Polygon'},
  'id': 'ABW',
  'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Italy', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
  'type': 'Feature'},
 {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036],
                                [-69.99693762899992, 12.577582098000036]]],
               'type': 'Polygon'},
  'id': 'ABW',
  'properties': {'ADMIN': 'Spain', 'ISO_A3': 'ABW'},
  'type': 'Feature'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The issue I'm now having is that geo_json from your example is actually a dictionary and not a list (sorry, wasn't clear in the question!). Any thoughts one how you might adjust the above to take that into consideration?

Comment: well it is a list of dictionaries, can  you post an example of your geojson file?

Comment: Thanks for your patience! For the example you shared, assume that geo_json is one big dictionary. I think the way you've shown it is a list containing a bunch of dictionaries within it. Again, I should've been more clear in the question on this, but thank you for the help regardless.

Comment: @J.Smith an example would really help

Comment: Looks like it was just a minor change to what you provided and it's working great! Thanks again for the assistance, VERY much appreciated :)

Comment: Awesome! If its working for you, you could mark as the answer